# chnage() function not working with Select list Items

Tags: jquery, html

HI Friends I am trying to show a `option value` in  `alert box` which shows when i change in `select Item list` but i failed to do that my code is below or you can also see the demo here http://jsfiddle.net/EXnkk/1/

**HTML**

```
<select name="select" id="editorFont">
                              <option value="arial">font 1</option>
                              <option value="alex_brushregular">font 2</option>
                              <option value="quicksandregular">font 3</option>
                            </select>
```

**SCRIPT**

```
$('select#editorFont').change(function (){
                var value = $(this).children('option').val;
                alert(value);
            })
```

Please help friends

Thanks in advance.. :)

Comment: `.val()` should be not just `val`, and add jQuery library to your fiddle.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try like

```
$('select#editorFont').on('change',function (){
    var value = $(this).val();
    alert(value);
});
```

And you need to put it in `DOM ready`.See the [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/7f5S7/)

Comment: Thanks for help but its not showing alert.. :( check fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/EXnkk/3/

Comment: @Kamal, add jQuery to your fiddle or use Gautam3164's

Answer (score 0):

It would work simply as

```
$('#editorFont').change(function (){
            var value = $(this).val();
            alert(value);
        });
```

Answer (score -2):

**You need to use Callback Functions**

A callback function is executed after the current effect is 100% finished.

JavaScript statements are executed line by line. However, with effects, the next line of code can be run even though the effect is not finished. This can create errors.

To prevent this, you can create a callback function.

A callback function is executed after the current effect is finished.

Typical syntax: $(selector).hide(speed,callback);

**Examples**

The example below has a callback parameter that is a function that will be executed after the hide effect is completed:

```
$("button").click(function(){
  $("p").hide("slow",function(){
    alert("The paragraph is now hidden");
  });
});
```

The example below has no callback parameter, and the alert box will be displayed before the hide effect is completed:

```
$("button").click(function(){
  $("p").hide(1000);
  alert("The paragraph is now hidden");
});
```

**Get Content - text(), html(), and val()**

```
$("#btn1").click(function(){
  alert("Text: " + $("#test").text());
});
$("#btn2").click(function(){
  alert("HTML: " + $("#test").html());
});
```

Comment: Explain me how this can be wrong ?  So what he neet to use to get value. He need in this case ***Callback***

Comment: You posted your answer in the wrong question. Scroll up... and read the question, about `<select>`

Comment: Do u read what he say. He need to show opition value in alert. So if value exist callback will return val() and what is wrong than

Comment: There is no `$("p")`, no `$("#btn1")`, no `$("#test")` in this question... are you serious? " though the effect is not finished"?? what effect?

Comment: Do u see in my post where i say ***Examples*** if he working in JQ he must understand logic. He can change stupid $(selector) so what is problem than.

Comment: There are no paragraph to hide here.. just getting the value of a select `onchange`...

Comment: Didn't mean to nake you angry or offend you, but I honestly don't think this is an answer to this question. Anyway, it was downvoted. If you delete it you will get your reputation points back